# I want class A import class B, B class also import A, only for import types

Tags: typescript

The typescript compiler did not work

a.ts

```js
import B from "./b";

class A {
    value: number = 1;

    x(b: B){
        return this.value - b.value;
    };
};
```

b.ts

```js
import A from "./a";

class B {
    value: number = 2;

    y(a: A){
        return this.value + a.value;
    };
};
```

c.ts

```js
import A from "./a";
import B from "./b";

class C {
    z(){
        let a = new A(), b = new B();

        console.log(
            a.x(b) + b.y(a)
        );
    };
};
```

How should i do for import A in b.ts and also import B in a.ts ?
Does the `Triple-Slash Directives` works for me ?

Comment: [Relevant article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)

Comment: You are generating circular dependencies, which is a big issue and should be avoided. I'd recommend re-thinking your code (maybe using class that knows both A and B) and changing the way your classes know/import each other.

Comment: If you add your code's objective, maybe you can get help in refactoring it.

Comment: thanks, the question has been resolved.Early, I had used webpack for building typescript with `awesome-typescript-loader`, and the error was coming. Then i use the `ts-loader` to instead `awesome-typescript-loader`, no any errors here.

Answer (score 0):

With Webpack:
When i use the `awesome-typescript-loader`, the error was coming.
Then i use the `ts-loader` to instead `awesome-typescript-loader`, no any errors here.